# How to get the navigation bar back button size in Xamarin ios?

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller

I want to get the size of the navigation back button in the View class. How can I do that?

I can get the size of the Navigation bar though using,

```
NavigationController.NavigationBar.Frame;
```

But I'm having a really hard time trying to find out the back button's size.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: you can debug your UIView hierarchy using this one also : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/inspector/

Comment: None of the couple of answers helped my case :/

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the size of the navigation back button in the View
>   class. How can I do that?

You're actually looking for a 'NavigationItem' of the navigation controller rather than an item of the 'NavigationBar' which I always found weird, but it's just how apple have decided to implement the property.

I believe that there are a few ways that you can access this information, but here is a quick way to get the frame.

```
CGRect frame = NavigationController.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem.CustomView.Frame;
```